# Database Call from Class is failing

Tags: php, database

I'm trying to use an existing class which has my DB connection in it to make a call within a new class. Here is my code to do this:

```
class ajaxHandler {

protected static $db;

function __construct() {
  if (!class_exists('Db')) {
      include "db_class.php";
      $db = new Db();
  }
}

function show_contest_details ($contest_id){
  echo "The contest id is: ".$contest_id;
  $event__conetest_details = $db->select("SELECT * FROM FF_CREATE_EVENT");
} // end of show_contest_details function

}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: db in /var/www/ajax_class.php on line 18

Fatal error: Call to a member function select() on a non-object in /var/www/ajax_class.php on line 18
```

How can I use my DB class within this class?

Answer (score 2):

You've forgotten about `self::`:

```
class ajaxHandler {

  protected static $db;

  function __construct() {
      if (!class_exists('Db')) {
        include "db_class.php";
      }
      self::$db = new Db();
  }

  function show_contest_details ($contest_id){
    echo "The contest id is: ".$contest_id;
    $event__conetest_details = self::$db->select("SELECT * FROM FF_CREATE_EVENT");
  } // end of show_contest_details function

}
```

Second thing, it is better to move code creating instance of `Db` outside the conditional block. You may accidentally include `Db` in other place, and then `ajaxHandler` will stop working, and you will not understand easily why.

Answer (score 1):

You use `class_exists()` to test whether or not you have created the database. That is not correct. `class_exists()` checks if the class has been defined, which is true after PHP has loaded the file, not after it has created the first instatiation of the class. What you need is this:

```
class ajaxHandler {

protected static $db;

  function __construct() {
    if (is_null(self::$db)) {
      include "db_class.php";
      self::$db = new Db();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `$db` is static, so you should call it as `::$db`, not with `->`. And he was checking for existence of the class, but strangely coupled it with creation of instance of Db class, what isn't too wise. What if db has been included in different place by chance? Then he would never create instance of db;) And your code may cause include of db_class several time, what may not be demanded.

Comment: @michaJIS: That was a bit sloppy of me. I changed the answer and replaced `$this->db` by `self::$db`. Yes, this is a bit strange, and I also would not encourage this way of opening databases.